How do I create a "sound field" using steam-audio?
The Steam-Audio library docs say the following:

You can use Ambisonic audio clips for sound fields: sounds playing from many directions around the listener. Ambient sounds are often a good candidate for Ambisonics.
(https://valvesoftware.github.io/steam-audio/doc/unity/guide.html#spatialize-an-ambisonic-source)

I'm trying to implement rain ambiance and it seems like this is the correct use-case, but the docs have no examples and I couldn't find anything about "sound fields" anywhere else. Using an Ambisonic clip and turning ambisonics on for the audio player don't really do anything, and creating a literal field of audio players just causes bad polyphony (and seems wasteful).
Anyone knows what's the solution?
